# Combining the terms of two MuMIn subset of models to create new subset in R

Tags: r, subset, lm

I am conducting an analysis where I am chosing between variables in two steps. Step 1: choose the best variables and combinations of variables from each of two set of variables (e.g., intrinsic & extrinsic variables). Step 2: take the best variables combinations of each subset and create new set of models that only have the combination allowed by the variables preselected in each subset. I'm using the function `dredge` in the `MuMin` package.

I can easily subset by hand the combinations of variables as shown below.

Step 1: select combinations of variables for each set of variables

```
library(MuMIn)
data(Cement)
# Choosing between X1 & X2 - Set of variable #1
fm1 <- lm(y ~ X1 + X2, Cement, na.action = na.fail)
m1 <- dredge(fm1)
sm1 <- subset(m1, delta < 32) # delta < 32 is only chosen to have 2 selected models
sm1
# Global model call: lm(formula = y ~ X1 + X2, data = Cement, na.action = na.fail)
# ---
#   Model selection table 
#   (Intrc)    X1     X2 df  logLik  AICc delta weight
# 4   52.58 1.468 0.6623  4 -28.156  69.3  0.00      1
# 3   57.42       0.7891  3 -46.035 100.7 31.42      0

# Choosing between X3 & X4 - Set of variable #2
fm2 <- lm(y ~ X3 + X4, Cement, na.action = na.fail)
m2 <- dredge(fm2)
sm2 <- subset(m2, delta < 20)
sm2
# Global model call: lm(formula = y ~ X3 + X4, data = Cement, na.action = na.fail)
# ---
#  Model selection table 
#   (Intrc)   X3      X4 df  logLik  AICc delta weight
# 4   131.3 -1.2 -0.7246  4 -35.372  83.7  0.00      1
# 3   117.6      -0.7382  3 -45.872 100.4 16.67      0
```

Step 2: Look at models with the two sets of variables but include only the combinations selected above for each set.

```
# Only looking at the combinations chosen above with subset.
fm3 <- lm(y ~., Cement, na.action = na.fail)
m3 <- dredge(fm3, subset = ((X1 & X2) | X2) & ((X3 & X4) | X4))
m3
# Global model call: lm(formula = y ~ ., data = Cement, na.action = na.fail)
# ---
#  Model selection table  
#    (Intrc)    X1      X2      X3      X4 df  logLik  AICc delta weight
# 12   71.65 1.452  0.4161         -0.2365  5 -26.933  72.4  0.00  0.921
# 15  203.60       -0.9234 -1.4480 -1.5570  5 -29.734  78.0  5.60  0.056
# 16   62.41 1.551  0.5102  0.1019 -0.1441  6 -26.918  79.8  7.40  0.023
# 11   94.16        0.3109         -0.4569  4 -45.761 104.5 32.08  0.000
```

Using `subset` works great when you only have a few variables as in the case above, but in my case I have many more variables selected in each set.

Is there a way to do the same without having to specify the variables in the subset by hand?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't a nicest solution, but does what you want.

```
library(MuMIn)
options(na.action = na.fail)
fm1 <- lm(y ~ X1 + X2, Cement)
m1 <- dredge(fm1)
ms1 <- subset(m1, delta < 32)
fm2 <- lm(y ~ X3 + X4, Cement)
m2 <- dredge(fm2)
ms2 <- subset(m2, delta < 20)

a1 <- !is.na(ms1[, attr(ms1, "terms")])
a2 <- !is.na(ms2[, attr(ms2, "terms")])
allterms <- c(attr(ms1, "terms"), attr(ms2, "terms"))
allterms[allterms == "(Intercept)"] <- "1"
n1 <- nrow(a1)
n2 <- nrow(a2)

res <- vector("list", n1 * n2)
k <- 0L
for(i in 1L:n1) for(j in 1L:n2) {
    frm <- reformulate(allterms[c(a1[i, ], a2[j, ])], response = ".")
    res[[k <- k + 1L]] <- update(fm1, formula = frm)
}

model.sel(res)
# Model selection table 
#    (Intrc)    X1      X2      X3      X4 df  logLik  AICc delta weight
# 4    52.58 1.468  0.6623                  4 -28.156  69.3  0.00  0.566
# 2    71.65 1.452  0.4161         -0.2365  5 -26.933  72.4  3.13  0.119
# 3    48.19 1.696  0.6569  0.2500          5 -26.952  72.5  3.16  0.116
# 10  103.10 1.440                 -0.6140  4 -29.817  72.6  3.32  0.107
# ...
```